# Send http 404 header and show content

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-code-404

Im want send header 404 Not found and show my page "error not found. try to see this...".
But when im send header i see native-browser page "Oops! This link appears to be broken.".
How i can show my page content with correct header?
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some browsers think their error pages are smarter than the website's. As far as I know, only Google Chrome and Internet explorer do so.

When they receive a response [shorter or equal in length to 512 bytes](http://perso.hirlimann.net/~ludo/blog/archives/2008/09/chrome-and-404s.html), they decide the page is 'not descriptive enough', and show their own 404 error document. You may want to add a padding comment to your page to bypass this check; or even better, useful content to describe what happened to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers won't show your 404 page unless it's a certain number of bytes (512 is common).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237722/customized-404-not-found-with-php) will probably help you out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's something that happens at the HTTP server level. Therefore, you'll have to change your settings there.  I think in Apache you can add this to your .htaccess or httpd.conf file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /location/to/your-404.php
```