# Ascii art in HTML comments - fad or function?

Tags: html, tumblr, ascii-art

Lately I've seen several websites with large ASCII art headers in their HTML. I don't get the point and it seems like this must just be a fad. For instance, [tumblr.com](http://www.tumblr.com/) has it:

```
<!--

        .                                 .o8       oooo
      .o8                                "888       `888
    .o888oo oooo  oooo  ooo. .oo.  .oo.   888oooo.   888  oooo d8b
      888   `888  `888  `888P"Y88bP"Y88b  d88' `88b  888  `888""8P
      888    888   888   888   888   888  888   888  888   888
      888 .  888   888   888   888   888  888   888  888   888    .o.
      "888"  `V88V"V8P' o888o o888o o888o `Y8bod8P' o888o d888b   Y8P

-->
```

Adding this art to the file increases the size of each HTML download, which could equate to actual bandwidth cost increases on popular sites. I can't imagine why someone would do this on purpose unless they are just trying to be hip and cool and don't care about the extra bandwidth.

Is there a valid business reason for doing this? Is it a branding technique? Is it used to deter people from ripping off HTML and site designs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Adding this art to the file increases the size of each HTML download, which could equate to actual bandwidth cost increases on popular sites.

You already answered your own question. It is **Art**! It is not supposed (or at least, it is not *required*) to have mundane functional value. :)

Seriously: as far I know, it has zero technical justification. It's all about decoration, and an insider's way of  leaving a mark (after all, most people are not going to look into the markup). It's also fine: In times where DSL speeds are the norm in many target markets, the "bandwidth" argument is mostly a weak one. Every family photo you download weighs dozens, hundreds or thousands of times more.

The only useful use of ASCII art in HTML that I know of is [using it as padding for 404 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970093/include-after-php-404-header-returning-oops-this-link-appears-to-be-broken/3970126#3970126) to prevent some browsers from showing their standard error page.

Comment: This is precisely what my take on it was as well. However, your thoughts on 404 page padding is interesting and something I wasn't aware of. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I really like this. Of course it's "useless", and it consumes some bandwidth. But maybe it also generates some traffic, as people notice this and show it to each other. It's funny and can be understood by anyone, but still smells of engineering.

Maybe this is a step towards more people appreciating the beauty of our creations and "materials", the same way a lot of people appreciate nice (and useless) detailing on car engines, watch movements and bridges without really knowing anything about the inner workings? I certainly hope so :)

Comment: I like this idea too! It provides a way for a developer to leave their mark. I was hoping to hear of a practical use for it in order to justify adding something like this to my sites.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why someone would do this either. Then again, I'm not much of an artist. ;-)

The images almost certainly serve no useful function, and you're right about increasing the size of the HTML files per download (although, the *amount* by which you increase the size is probably negligible with the ubiquity of high-speed connections today).

I'm also not sure it can properly be labeled a "fad"—I haven't seen this nearly often as other social fads like [crocs](http://www.crocs.com/) and [iPods](http://www.apple.com/ipod).

There's no way this would deter people from ripping off HTML and site designs. If you have no conscience that stops you from blatantly ripping off people's designs and source, you'll have absolutely no reason not to yank out the giant comment block at the top, whether it has a pretty design or not.

It's probably best to think of this like an ["easter egg"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29) in a traditional software program. Relatively few people are likely to see it (the average person rarely looks at a page's source code), but it's the programmer's way of leaving their individual mark on their work.

Comment: Easter egg is a much better term than fad! I can't recall the other sites I've seen this in, but I'm sure I've seen it in 3 or 4 sites in the last month. I realize this won't stop people with no conscience, but those with half-a-conscience might think twice. And as far as bandwidth goes, I meant google-scale, where the home page is hit millions of times a day, and an extra 1K per hit would add up.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but some HTML comment art does serve a purpose. I would suspect it serves a double purpose, to be art (as other answers have pointed out) and to act as a test which I would guess makes it worth the extra bandwidth.

> The "meow duck" is famously a feature with its own set of unit tests to make sure it's always present in the output code.
>   - [Reddit user Skookah](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/724hbo/found_this_in_amazons_markup/)

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems to me to have understood, the Ascii art serve to break in a strongly visual way a piece of code from another.
For example, if you have a piece of code in html and we want to add a piece of javascript inline, with the `script` tag, then you can put an Ascii Art.
For my codebase I create them from **here**:
http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20

They are of every shape and size!