# 404 Page not showing up in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, http-status-code-404, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [include after PHP 404 header returning “Oops! This link appears to be broken.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970093/include-after-php-404-header-returning-oops-this-link-appears-to-be-broken)

I have a custom 404 page in Play! project. For some reason, I'm noticing that the 404 page appears on all browsers EXCEPT IE9--which just shows a default page not found for the browser. Is there any reason for this? Right now  I have it implemented in the Global class in the default class path. So when the resource is not found, it forwards to the error page after reaching the handler not found function. Thanks!

Comment: How large is your 404 file? Is it smaller than 512 bytes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 404 page needs to be more than a certain size (For IE, IIRC it's 512 bytes) to be displayed instead of the default "page not found". See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970093/include-after-php-404-header-returning-oops-this-link-appears-to-be-broken)